# I cannot get INSERT INTO tablename etc to work in Python 3.8 pyodbc MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql-insert, pyodbc, python-3.8

I am fairly certain that connection to the database has been established.
Here's my code...

```
#
# *************************************************************************************************************************************
# * ADDKEYWORD processing
# *************************************************************************************************************************************
#    
def addkeyword(ktyp, kword, kweight):
    tbkeywordtype = str(ktyp)
    tbkeyword = str(kword)
    tbweighting = float(kweight)
#    
    tbkeywordkey = 1   # temporary work around
#
# Prepare string for inserting new tbkeyword record
#    
    insertString = str
    insertString = "\"INSERT INTO tbkeyword (KeywordKey, KeywordType, Keyword, Weighting, Added, Updated) VALUES (%s,'%s','%s',%s,'%s','%s');\"" % (tbkeywordkey,tbkeywordtype,tbkeyword,tbweighting,formatted_date,formatted_date)
    print(insertString)
#
# Insert new tbkeyword record
#
    mycursor.execute(insertString)
#
# Check status code to go here
#
    mydb.commit
```

Here's the result.   Note that in the first line(s) is the outcome from a print of the string that will be inbetween the parentheses of the mycursor.execute().

"INSERT INTO tbkeyword (KeywordKey, KeywordType, Keyword, Weighting, Added, Updated) VALUES (1,'K','free',0.6,'2019-11-19 09:12:08','2019-11-19 09:12:08');"

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Tony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\MainMenuGUI.py", line 185, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: addkeyword(ektyp.get(),ekword.get(),eweight.get()))
  File "C:\Users\Tony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\MainMenuGUI.py", line 103, in addkeyword
    mycursor.execute(insertString)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-8.0.18]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'"INSERT INTO tbkeyword (KeywordKey, KeywordType, Keyword, Weighting, Added, Upda\' at line 1 (1064) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I simply cannot see what I have done wrong.   Help!!!!

Comment: Why does your `insertString` contain quote marks?

Comment: You are correct!   They appeared to be shown in every example that I found online.

Comment: EXCEPT that the commit doesn't seem to have worked! :(

Comment: Just remove \" at the beginning and end of your query string

Comment: Everything working fine.   How do I get this problem closed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are inserting " in your query string. Just remove them (at the beginning and end):

```
   insertString = str
   insertString = "INSERT INTO tbkeyword (KeywordKey, KeywordType, Keyword, Weighting, Added, Updated) VALUES (%s,'%s','%s',%s,'%s','%s');" % (tbkeywordkey,tbkeywordtype,tbkeyword,tbweighting,formatted_date,formatted_date)
   print(insertString)
   #
   # Insert new tbkeyword record
   #
   mycursor.execute(insertString)
```

But it will be better if you also use prepared statements and remove the lines you don 't need like this:

```
insertString = "INSERT INTO tbkeyword (KeywordKey, KeywordType, Keyword, Weighting, Added, Updated) 
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);"     
# print(insertString)
#
# Insert new tbkeyword record
#
mycursor.execute(insertString,(tbkeywordkey,tbkeywordtype,tbkeyword,tbweighting,formatted_date,formatted_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using tripple quotes around your query string (but I dont recommend using this over prepared statements.)

```
insertString = """INSERT INTO tbkeyword (KeywordKey, KeywordType, Keyword, Weighting, Added, Updated) VALUES (%s,'%s','%s',%s,'%s','%s');""" % (tbkeywordkey,tbkeywordtype,tbkeyword,tbweighting,formatted_date,formatted_date)
```

- there seems to be missing ' ' around your first %s after VALUES (%s